# How to use tee or > within "screen" while also supplying the name of the screen to them?

Tags: shell, exec, gnu-screen, tee

I am trying to start a number of jobs in different screens from a shell script. Each job will read in a different value of a parameter from a premade input file and run a simulation based on that value, then tee or > the output to a differently named file. So in a do loop around all the jobs, job 40 on screen "session40" will read in line 40 of the input file, run the simulation, and output to output40.dat, for example. (I am basically trying to run a few jobs in parallel in a very elementary way; it appears my computer has plenty of RAM for this).

I am encountering the issue that the > and | tee commands do not seem to work when I use "exec" to run a command on the remote screen, despite having attempted to start a bash shell there; when I use these commands, it just prints to standard output. Although these commands do work with the command "stuff," I do not know how to pass the job number to stuff, as it appears to only work with string inputs.

The current attempted script is as follows. I have replaced the simulation script with `echo` and `>` for a simpler example of the problem. Neither of the last two screen lines work.

```
for i in 1:10; do

screen -Sdm session$i bash

screen -S session$i -X exec echo $i > runnumber$i.output (method 1)

screen -S session$i -X stuff $'echo $i > runnumber$i.output\r' (method 2)

done
```

Might there be an easy fix?